# Node/Typescript: How to close a writestream in the process 'exit' event - red/blue function problem / async infection

Tags: node.js, typescript, asynchronous, fs

In [my current FOSS Discord bot project](https://github.com/thetayloredman/ProtoBot) I have this `log.ts` file which handles the logging for the bot.

It creates multiple `fs.WriteStream` objects, which write to each log file. There is a section in the code when `await log('CLOSE_STREAMS')` is called to run the `WriteStream#close()` functions on each WriteStream, returning a promise. This is used in the `process.on('exit')` handler to save the log files before we close.

The problem here is that the `'exit'` event handler can not schedule any additional work into the event queue.

How could I handle calling the CLOSE_STREAMS in a way where I can run this exit handler as I am expecting?

### Function Implementation, simplified

#### log.ts `log('CLOSE_STREAMS')`

```
// Main
export default function log(mode: 'CLOSE_STREAMS'): Promise<void>;
export default function log(mode: 'v' | 'i' | 'w' | 'e', message: any, _bypassStackPrint?: boolean): void;
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
export default function log(mode: 'v' | 'i' | 'w' | 'e' | 'CLOSE_STREAMS', message?: any, _bypassStackPrint = false): void | Promise<void> {
    if (mode === 'CLOSE_STREAMS')
        // Close all of the file streams
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            errStr.end(() => {
                warnStr.end(() => {
                    allStr.end(() => {
                        resolve();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    else {
```

#### index.ts

This is the way the log is killed in the uncaught exceptions; this would be how I want to do it for the exit event.

```
// If we get an uncaught exception, close ASAP.
process.on('uncaughtException', async (error) => {
    log('e', 'Killing client...', true);
    client.destroy();
    log('e', 'Client killed.', true);
    log('e', 'Closing databases...', true);
    client.closeDatabases();
    log('e', 'Closed databases.', true);
    log('e', 'An uncaught exception occured!', true);
    log('e', `Error thrown was:`, true);
    error.stack?.split('\n').forEach((item) => {
        log('e', `${item}`, true);
    });
    log('e', 'Stack trace dump:', true);
    let stack = new Error().stack?.split('\n');
    stack?.shift();
    if (!stack) stack = [];

    stack.forEach((item) => {
        log('e', `${item}`, true);
    });
    log('e', 'Process exiting.', true);
    log('e', 'Exit code 5.', true);
    log('e', 'Goodbye!', true);
    await log('CLOSE_STREAMS'); // <<<<<<<<<<<< HERE
    process.exit(5);
});
```

Comment: You can use synchronous file operations in an exit event.  As you seem to already know, you cannot reliably use asynchronous file operations.

Comment: @jfriend00 I do know this... but how do I close my log file? Should I replace the writable stream with a fs.writeFileSync() operation *every time the log is called*? Or should I batch logs in an array and write every x seconds (or on SYNC)?

Comment: I doubt you want to make all log file writing synchronous as that could very well interfere with the responsiveness of the rest of your bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, you can't reliably use asynchronous operations in the processing of an exit event because the process will exit before they complete.  As such, I don't think there's any way to do this reliably with a nodejs stream.  Streams have a completely asynchronous API and implementation, including flushing and closing.

In a few Google searches I found a few other people [asking for the same thing](https://github.com/nodejs/readable-stream/issues/341) for the same reasons and there was no solution offered.  As best I know, these are the options:

1. Do some hacking on the stream object to add a synchronous `flushAndClose()` method to your stream.  You'd have to work into the internals of the stream to get the buffer and the file handle and do your own synchronous write of any remaining buffer and then do a synchronous close on the file handle.  Note, even this has a problem case if there's currently an asynchronous write operation in process.
2. Abandon the built-in stream and just implement your own lightweight logfile interface that makes it easy for you to have both asynchronous writing (for normal use) and a synchronous `flushAndClose()` operation for emergency shut-down.  Note, even this has a problem case if there's currently an asynchronous write operation in process when you want to do the synchronous close.
3. Rather than using `process.on('exit', ...)` to trigger closing of the log files, go up one level higher in the chain.  Whatever it is that triggers closing of your app, put it in an async function that will wait for the log files to be properly closed before calling `process.exit()` so you get the log files closed when you still have the ability to handle asynchronous operations.
4. Do logging from a different (more stable) process.  This process can then message that logging process what it wants logged and that process can manage getting the logging info safely to disk independent of whether the source process shuts down abruptly or not.

Note: Exiting a process will automatically close any open file selectors (the OS takes care of that for you).  So, as long as this is an edge case shut-down in some fatal error condition, not a common normal shut-down, then perhaps you don't have a big problem here to really solve.

The worst that could happen is that you might lose some very recently logged lines of data if they hadn't yet been flushed from the stream.  Note that streams write data immediately to their descriptor when possible so they don't generally accumulate lots of buffered data.  The time when they do buffer data is when a new write to the stream happens, but the previous write is still in operation.  Then the data to be written gets buffered until the prior write operation completes.  So, data is never left sitting in the buffer with an idle stream.  This tends to minimize (though not eliminate) data loss on an immediate shut-down.

If this is a normal, regular shut-down, then you should be able to use option #3 above and reshape how the shut-down occurs so you can use asynchronous code where you want so you can properly shutdown the streams.

Comment: So... based on my bot's infrastructure, could I implement an `async shutdownProcess()` function on my custom `(import 'discord').Client` interface which would run the DB closes and the process exit? What if this is called in a synchronous case? I'm assuming that I would need to make all of the functions below it's call async as well, or can I just call it with a non-await context?

Comment: I started using this case when I had data loss on SIGTERM and errors; which meant the stack trace was kept *nowhere.* I could also consider handling logging in the parent process (`start.sh`)?

Comment: @0xLogN - Interesting you mention another process.  That was the other thought I had for reliable logging.  If you have the actual logging to disk implemented by another process (not a child-process that will die if the parent does), then the `log()` function messages the logging process with the log data and then the logging process handles it from then one.  The main process can die and, if so, the logging process (which was monitoring the main process) will make sure everything is flushed to disk and then close and then shut itself down.

Comment: @0xLogN - I don't know discord at all so I can't help you with how to best use its APIs.

Comment: That's not it's API specifically; it's my extension of the Client. @jfriend00

Comment: The bot is run by a parent Bash script; I can make it handle the disk writes *before* re-running the bot.

Comment: @0xLogN - OK, I added option #4 to do logging in another, more stable process.

Comment: I have accepted your solution as it's the best there is. Is there some sort of credit you'd like in the PR i make to add the changes?

Comment: @0xLogN - Just glad to help.  Nothing else needed.

Comment: Wait a minute... we have this reply: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21207#issuecomment-395723983 -- is this possible?

Comment: @0xLogN - I have no idea how that could possibly work and, in fact, it doesn't even make sense.  You can't write to a `null` filename and I have no idea why writing `{fd}` would do anything useful.  Plus it doesn't even show where `fd` comes from.  So, none of that makes any sense to me.  Plus `fs.writeFileSync()` clears the contents of the file before writing to it.